# PowerBI Report Builder and swapping rows and columns

Tags: powerbi

I am evaluating PowerBI Report Builder to create paginated reports. I am new to this product, so may have missed something- however I have tried to google an answer for my problem, and have not had any luck

I have a simple MonthlyData table which records different measures of different datatypes.  I can easily create the report like shown under the link below:
[Report I can make happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP883.jpg)

What I need to do is swap rows and columns so the report shows like this in the link below:

[Report I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gUsY.png)

I could see how using ColumnGroups and RowGroups could attain the results I need if all the measures were the save datatype, but they aren't.  I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Any guidance on how to attain this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Apologies if I am missing something.  I know there is a Power Query Editor in PowerBI desktop.  I am evaluating the PowerBI Report Builder - I cant seen to find the Power Query Editor in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap rows and columns you just import your data then go to table view
then go through the home tab and click on transform data button, then a new power query editor will be open then you just drag and drop the cloumn and rows you want to swap infront to the row and column you want to swap with.

I guess it will be helpfull.